# How to configure a NSTextView with a NSTextStorage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nstextstorage

How do you store the NSTextView's information with an NSTextStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently each NSTextView comes with it's own NSTextStorage already.  Just use the textStorage method to get the textStorage of the NSTextView

Comment: I keep getting `nil` for that.

Answer (score 3):

See [Assembling the Text System by Hand](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextSystemArchitecture/ArchitectureOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH7-SW10) in the [Cocoa Text Architecture Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/CocoaTextArchitecture.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, however I have figured it out how to do that by using NSTextView's textStorage.